# How to use a function pointer that is a member of a structure

Tags: c

I have a structure that has a function as one of it's members. 
Like

```
    Creature.move = moveAway;
```

moveAway being name of the function.
So how can you exactly use that function?

Comment: C does not allow function members, as it is no OOP language. You might confuse with C++. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not have member functions, which means that your member apparently is not a function, but a function *pointer*. In order to call the target function through that pointer it you have a choice of either

```
Creature.move( /* arguments */ );
```

or

```
(*Creature.move)( /* arguments */ );
```

Choose whichever you like best. Both variants do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The member is a function pointer, and you can call it just like a normal function:

```
Creature.move();
```

Or, if it takes further arguments:

```
Creature.move(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

(You can dereference the function pointer first if you like, but it'll just decay right back to a function pointer: `(*Creature.move)();`, `(**Creature.move)();`, `(*****Creature.move)();`, ...)

Comment: Hmm, being a 6-star C-programmer ... ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Oh, I did not doubt it is legal. There just come some interresting meta-coding applications for this into mind:-)

Comment: @Olaf: The demo wasn't for you! I had created it before you even made your comment.